# Linear Algebra, want to find $A, B, C, and/or D$

Tags: linear-algebra

I feel like I should be able to find A, B, C and/or D with these equations. (I am trying to make a crafting formula in Excel from a game I'm playing and am off the impression that each material is giving a fixed amount of statistics to the item, I need to know the value of 1 material to find the rest by looking at differences from the 1 known value)

Here are the equations:

A+B=22,75

A+C=28,05

D+B=23,19

D+C=28,49

Considering I can figure out the differences between A&D=0,44 and B&C=5,3 I felt like it should be possible to find what A is. But my efforts so far leave me with a 0=0 solution.

If the equations above prove that A is different in A+B than in A+C. I would be happy about that aswell. It means the game alters the materials statistic based on what it is combined with.

Comment: This is a system of linear equations. Read about Gaussian elimination: https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/algebra/linear-algebra/linear-systems/gaussian-elimination

Comment: There are infinitely many values of $A$ which will satisfy this system of linear equations.

Answer (score 1):

The system is underdetermined:

If you substract the second equation from the first, you find a value for $B-C$. Similarly, if you substract the last equation from the third. Fortunately, both values are equal.

In a similar way, you can subtract the third/fourth equation from the first/second and find a value for $A-D$. Again you are lucky that both values are equal.

So you have a linear system with determinant $0$, but fortunately the right-hand side is of such a type that there exists a solution (actually an infinite number of solutions, depending on a free parameter).

For instance, you can fix an arbitrary value for $B$. Then the first equation gives a value for $A$ (in terms of $B$ and some constants), inserting $A$ into thee second equation then gives a value for $C$ (again in terms of $B$ and some constants), and the third equation gives a value for $D$ in terms of $B$ and a constant.

The last equation is not needed, but as we saw before, it must be consistent with the calculated values.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your system does not have a single solution, it has infinitely many solutions. You can see that subtracting second equation from the first and subtracting fourth from the third will give you $B-C=-5.3$. Thus, you only have three equations with four variables.

Comment: Jepp. Its as far as I got. Thank you though for checking. :) 

I assume that it will not help having more A+?=numbers as the game has 32 different materials. I guess I would just end up knowing the differences between all 32 materials but not knowing their exact number individually.

Comment: @Serfuz: if you can get A+D to replace the first equation, it would help

Answer (score 0):

Te first two equations and the second two give the same result taking the difference, so the are not independent. You can choose one of the A,B,C,D as any value you choose and then find the others.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. It appears I need to find some other/additional constant number that can help determine A. As I believe the game has set a definitive number for each material. So choosing an arbitrary number will "solve" the equation. But not actually finding the specific number I want to find. :)